# How to deminify next.js html from internet

Tags: javascript, html, next.js

I'm trying to rebuild a website that I scraped from the web using wget. It appears to be a next js application, as I see the _next folder. I have 0 experience in nextjs and have no idea what the inner workings are, but it seems like it is somehow minifying all the code into a single script.

Is there any way to "undo" this and make it look like pretty HTML?

Here is what it looks like
[image: Here is what it looks like]

[image: Directories]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible, as the HTML you scraped is pre-rendered static HTML by NextJS that's later hydrated by the JavaScript, which resides in the `chunks` folder.

To recreate the website, you'll first have to recreate all the JavaScript that was transpiled into chunks by WebPack or SWC, which is no easy task. It's laborious and can only be minimally automated, and there's no way to "demangle" code that's been transpiled back into its original form.

There might be a better solution to your question if you provide more information about your target and motivation behind doing so. Otherwise, I'd strongly recommend not spending time trying to reverse transpiled code.

Comment: I don't have access to the source for a next.js app that is almost purely static HTML with one form. I am trying to rebuild the website so I can change some details and don't know if I have to rebuild the whole thing.

Comment: Does the HTML work in this mangled form?

Comment: Yes I started a webserver and put the mangled code on and it worked.